# Display the calculation of servlet before forwarding it to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I wrote a code in servlet to perform addition of two numbers and display it and forward the servlet to another jsp. But, the result of addition is not displayed.

It only forwards to the jsp page without showing the result.

```
public class Add extends HttpServlet {
    public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        int i=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("t1"));
        int j=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("t2"));
        int k=i+j;
        request.setAttribute("sum",k);
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/Welcome.jsp");
        rd.forward(request,response);
    }

}
```

JSP code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<HTML>
<HEAD> <TITLE> The Welcome JSP  </TITLE> </HEAD>
<BODY>
<H3> Welcome! </H3>
<% request.getAttribute("sum"); %>
<P><B> Today is.  Have a nice day! </B></P>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I want the output as The sum is...... and the remaining jsp part. The servlet is forwarded to the jsp page but the sum is not displayed.

Comment: you could also use `response.sendRedirect("/Welcome.jsp?sum=" + k);`

Comment: On the JSP page change this `<% request.getAttribute("sum"); %>`  to  `<%= request.getAttribute("sum") %>`

Comment: I added this to servlet
request.getSession().setAttribute("sum", k);
        response.sendRedirect("/Welcome.jsp?sum=" + k);
and this to jsp:
<%= request.getAttribute("sum") %>
I am getting null as result

Comment: On your servlet just write `response.sendRedirect("/Welcome.jsp?sum=" + k);` after `int k=i+j;` and nothing else.

Comment: Forget `session` for now. That is obviously an option but you don't need that.